# Add row not working for Matrix field in Safecracker form

Tags: matrix, safecracker

I'm building a safecracker frontend form that allow members to update certain objects.  This form uses a matrix field for managing opening hours of shops

The matrix field displays fine and existing data can be update without any problem.  However the '+' sign does not seem to work to add new rows.

It believe it is a javascript problem as the console show

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'markItUp'
```

What can be wrong?

rg,

Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably including jquery twice on the same page. Use safecracker's `include_jquery="no"` parameter. Also, be sure to include jQuery before any safecracker code. If you want to place all scripts at the bottom of the body, you can use Stash to grab the {safecracker_head} variable and place it wherever you like.

https://github.com/croxton/Stash/

Comment: Stupid me... you are 100% right, I'm including jquery twice.